# JPA boolean default = false @transient

Tags: java, jpa

How can i set the default value of a @transient boolean to false?
Everytime i get my object the value is true.
I tried with "@Column(nullable=false, columnDefinition="boolean default false") " but doesn't work

Thx =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this

```
@Transient
private boolean myField = false;
```

Btw, `@Column` has no effect on transient fields.

Comment: Then you have some other code that is updating the field. Note that if your entity is in hibernate's L2 cache, if you refresh it from the database it'll only refresh persistent fields. So if you changed this transient field to `true` at some point, it will remain `true` after the refresh.

Comment: Oh actually it works, i just forgot to clear my entitymanager :D ty